# Basic action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, I can't get jQuery to do what I want it to do.

What I need is for the container div to disappear when one of its children is clicked.

Here's example HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <a href="link">
  <div id="child1">
   When this is clicked, #container disappears,
   including everything contained inside...
  </div>
 </a>

 <a href="link">
  <div id="child2">
   ...or when this one is clicked
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
$("#child1").click(function () { 
  $(#container).hide(); 
});
```

and

```
$("#child1").click(function () { 
  $(#container).fadeOut("fast"); 
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "For some reason, I can't get jQuery to do what I want it to do" How's that then?

Comment: for some reason I don't feel like answering this question

Comment: `$(#container)` is not valid JS. `$("#child1")` is correct though. That should give you a hint.

Comment: for some reason I am too lazy to learn jquery

Comment: ...you usually put block elements (div) inside inline elements (a)?

Comment: What's wrong with that? The HTML I demonstrate above is just an example. The actual content inside the div I'm using (represented above as "#child1") contains more child divs and I need everything inside that div to be one link.

Comment: Inline elements just cannot contain block elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, no matter how many elements you have in your `#container` div, clicking on them will hide the whole div :

```
$("#container").children().bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $("#container").fadeOut();
});
```

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/Bd9Dc/

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Is there anyway I can specify specific trigger ids?

Comment: "trigger ids" ? You mean hide the container only if particular children are clicked ? Like that : `$("#container").children("#YOURID1,#YOURID2")...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#child1, #child2").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents("#container").hide();
}
```

Something like that? Or more like

```
$("#container").children("div").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents("#container").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").children().click(function(e) {
    $("#container").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, your selectors are not valid strings.
`$(#container)` will throw a syntax error, because the syntax should be `$(selector)` where `selector` is a `string` or an object.
So, just update your selectors from

```
$(#container)
```

to

```
$('#container')
```

Note : even this site's syntax highlighter gives you a hint that something is wrong!